# Redactor wysiwyg image upload not working and no errors

Tags: codeigniter, redactor

I'm trying to implement redactor wysiwyg and I have problems with image upload.

Controller

```
public function upload()
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => './uploads',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
        'max_size' => '60000',
        'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
        'remove_spaces' => TRUE
    );
    // load upload library and initialize config file
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {           
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $json = array(
            'filelink' => base_url("uploads/{$image_data['file_name']}")
        );
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($json));
    }   
}
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#redactor').redactor({ 
            imageUpload: "http://localhost/rms2/admin/pages/upload",  
            minHeight: 150
        });
    }
);

</script>

<?php echo form_open_multipart($this->uri->uri_string())?>
   <div class="form">
     <div class="horizontal">
       <div class="label"><?php echo form_label('Description', 'description')?></div>
       <div class="input"><?php echo form_textarea('description', set_value('description'), 'id="redactor"')?></div>
       <div class="form_error"><?php echo form_error('description')?></div>
</div>
.....
```

The main problem is that I don't get any errors when I try to upload a image and if I drag it I get the message loading 100% like the image is uploaded, but no image, in the source file no  tag, nothing.

Did anybody encounter this problem ??

**EDIT**:

The link provided to image upload is not getting requested as I tried with a link outside CI(just a simple php file upload) and it works just fine, design pattern of the system is HMVC, anybody willing to give a hand or suggestions?

Comment: do you have error reporting enabled in your apache/php ?

Comment: yeah everything is on :(

Answer (score 0):

I've read here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/229243/#1039307

that you have to change your uploadsdir to something like:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/images';
```

Create those folders and then it should work fine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: still nothing, I tried to to put if !$this->upload die ('error') and upload->display_errors() and still nothing, by the way I just found this editor and I have a trial version as I wanted to see how it is before I buy, do you thing this should cause a problem?

Comment: and I tried early on the code from that thread and it wasn't working, so the upload path I don't really think is that important

Comment: hm. you could provide that on your code. but no problem. we just need to fix this.

Comment: try a var_dump on your $image_data and see what that does. does it output the uploaded image?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the request is not done on upload because I tried their script outside codeigniter in pure php and I had an error on upload directory and I've got an javascript alert with "Upload error..." and after I fixed that worked just fine, so the problem is somewhere else ?!

Comment: I tried var dump but I get no results, so its kind of clear enough that redactor doesn't make the request to upload?

Comment: yes. no images were uploaded so it's a problem with redactor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27924/discussion-between-lesandru-and-kees-sonnema)